# Do I have to commit a merge to make git-rerere record my conflict resolution?

Tags: git, merge-conflict-resolution, git-rerere

I'm using `git-rerere` for its intended purpose, to record conflict resolutions between two branches (master and a topic branch) incrementally as those branches develop, without creating unnecessary merge commits. However, even after reading the git-rerere manpage I'm a little unclear on when rerere actually records my conflict resolution. My standard workflow for detecting and resolving new merge conflicts is to do `git merge master` from the topic branch, resolve the conflicts, then stage all the files and commit the merge with `git commit -m "Finished test merge"`, and then undo the merge using `git reset --hard HEAD^`, leaving behind only the recorded resolutions stored by `git-rerere`.

However, this seems a bit silly. Creating a commit and then undoing it just to record the resolution? After reading the manpage for `git-rerere`, I'm still not really clear on when it records my resolutions. Is it sufficient to just stage the conflicted files or do I actually need to create the merge commit after resolving the conflicts, like I've been doing?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

From the manpage:

```
Running the git rerere command immediately after a conflicted automerge
records the conflicted working tree files, with the usual conflict
markers <<<<<<<, =======, and >>>>>>> in them. Later, after you are
done resolving the conflicts, running git rerere again will record the
resolved state of these files.
```

And:

```
As a convenience measure, git merge automatically invokes git rerere
upon exiting with a failed automerge and git rerere records the hand
resolve when it is a new conflict, or reuses the earlier hand resolve
when it is not. git commit also invokes git rerere when committing a
merge result. What this means is that you do not have to do anything
special yourself (besides enabling the rerere.enabled config variable).
```

So you don't have to commit and undo the commit. You can just run `git rerere` without parameters to record the commit.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it sufficient to just stage the conflicted files

You must be sure to resolve the conflict without leaving conflict markers.

See [commit f427869](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f427869bde759e32c30e8ba7a4b20837d3806642), [commit bc4caec](https://github.com/git/git/commit/bc4caecf9557c765951897d8483b1514ebae74bf) (28 Aug 2018) by [Thomas Gummerer (`tgummerer`)](https://github.com/tgummerer).
Suggested-by: [Junio C Hamano (`gitster`)](https://github.com/gitster).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit d88949d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d88949d86eddb62acbc85c16c97587db043d05b1), 17 Sep 2018)</sup>

See [commit b9b07ef](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b9b07efdb2ac35684d3ee3fe98f91691d5b8642a) (28 Aug 2018) by [Thomas Gummerer (`tgummerer`)](https://github.com/tgummerer).
Helped-by: [Junio C Hamano (`gitster`)](https://github.com/gitster).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 4dd0c4a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4dd0c4a44cf9500f3197062da1a82a83a867fb94), 17 Sep 2018)</sup>

> ### `.gitattributes`: add conflict-marker-size for relevant files
>
> Some files in [`git.git`](https://github.com/git/git/) contain lines that look like conflict markers, either in examples or tests, or in the case of [`Documentation/gitk.txt`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/150f307afc13961b0322ad0e7205a7b193368586/Documentation/gitk.txt) because of the asciidoc heading.
>
> Having conflict markers the same length as the actual content can be confusing for humans, and **is impossible to handle for tools like '`git rerere`'**.
>
> Work around that by setting the '`conflict-marker-size`' attribute for those files to 32, which makes the conflict markers unambiguous.