# Can git rerere be applied retroactively?

Tags: git

I just learned about `git rerere` as I'm preparing to rebase a long-lived branch on top of master.

[What is git-rerere and how does it work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49500943/what-is-git-rerere-and-how-does-it-work)

I have merged master *into* my branch a few times already, but only enabled `rerere` afterwards.

Is there a way to 'seed' the `rerere` database with these already-existing merge commits? (so when I finally do the rebase, I can benefit from replaying the conflict resolutions in these older commits)

Comment: See https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/rerere-train.sh - basically you turn `rerere` on, then re-perform the merge, grab the merge result from the existing merge, save it, discard the deliberately failed merge, and keep going.

Comment: Or see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23857349/re-use-conflict-resolution-with-git/23861395#23861395).