# Is there a reason Git ReReRe might not succeed?

Tags: git, git-rerere

I have an integration branch that I use to test multiple features at once. Sometimes the features conflict with each other, and Git ReReRe has been invaluable in helping to avoid re-doing the resolution.

But this time, I have a file for which I have a resolution in `rr-cache`, Git uses the resolution, but then complains I have to resolve the conflict myself.

```
Simple merge did not work, trying automatic merge.
Auto-merging src/file1.xxx
ERROR: content conflict in src/file1.xxx
Auto-merging src/file2.xxx
Auto-merging src/file3.xxx
fatal: merge program failed
Resolved 'src/file1.xxx' using previous resolution.
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
```

```
$ git status
On branch integration
You have unmerged paths.
  (fix conflicts and run "git commit")
  (use "git merge --abort" to abort the merge)

Changes to be committed:
    (...more files...)
    modified:   src/file2.xxx
    modified:   src/file3.xxx

Unmerged paths:
  (use "git add <file>..." to mark resolution)
    both modified:   src/file1.xxx
```

I've tried `git rerere forget src/file1.xxx` and letting it recreate the ReReRe resolution. I've even tried setting the `postimage` by hand. But nothing seems to convince Git that the `postimage` should be applied and accepted.

It's not a difficult conflict, but I'd really like it to happen seamlessly.

Comment: Maybe check out [conflict marker length](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52460841/241211).

Comment: This is normal: the reused resolution is not *accepted*, it's just stored in the working tree copy for you to try out. You still have to run `git add` to accept it (and are encouraged to inspect and/or test it first).